# Map function can't seem to render components inline

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a state(keys) that I update from a form. The update works nicely, and I can keep adding keys to the form and they are rendered. However, each key gets rendered on a new line. I think I am making correct use of flexDirection, but I'm stumped.

```
renderKeys = () => {
    return (
        <ScrollView style={{marginLeft:'5%', paddingTop: '2%', marginBottom:'5%',
            marginRight: '5%', flexDirection: 'row', borderWidth:1, borderColor:'red'}}>
            {
                this.state.keys.map((key) =>
                    <View
                        style={{
                            borderRadius:10,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: '#fff',
                            backgroundColor: 'white',
                            flexDirection: 'row',
                        }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.deleteKey()}>
                            <EvilIcon
                                name='close'
                                type='evilicon'
                                color='#517fa4'
                                size={15}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={{color:'black', flex:1}}>{key}</Text>
                    </View>
                )
            }
        </ScrollView>
        )
    }
```

This is called from my render method like this:

```
                    <View style={{borderWidth:1}}>
                        {this.renderKeys()}
                    </View>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting these to render side-by-side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you should find that a `<View />` component within the `<ScrollView />` that uses the `flexWrap` style rule should solve your problem:

```
renderKeys = () => {
  return (
      <ScrollView style={{marginLeft:'5%', paddingTop: '2%', marginBottom:'5%',
          marginRight: '5%', borderWidth:1, borderColor:'red'}}>
          <View style={{ flexWrap : 'wrap', flexDirection : 'row' }}>
          {
              this.state.keys.map((key) =>
                  <View
                      style={{
                          borderRadius:10,
                          borderWidth: 1,
                          borderColor: '#fff',
                          backgroundColor: 'white',
                          flexDirection: 'row',
                      }}>
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.deleteKey()}>
                          <EvilIcon
                              name='close'
                              type='evilicon'
                              color='#517fa4'
                              size={15}
                          />
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                      <Text style={{color:'black', flex:1}}>{key}</Text>
                  </View>
              )
          }
          </View>
      </ScrollView>
      )
  }
```

The `<ScrollView/>` component typically doesn't respond to layout styling in the same way that `<View />` does, so usually it's best to nest things like tags in an intermediate `<View />` component like this.

The `flexWrap` rule combined with `flexDirection : row` basically causes children to list on a new line if horizontal space on the current line runs out.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome!! I've been stuck on this for two days haha. Why does this work?

Comment: I think scroll view expects a child view, on that view you can apply flex rules.

Comment: Hey you're welcome - glad I could help. `ScrollView` typically doesn't layout children in the sameway that `View` does, so usually best to nest things like tags in a `View`. The `flexWrap` rule causes children to list on a new line if horizontal space on the current line runs out.